# How to get around a 'NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE' error using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im just writing a small Ajax framework for re-usability in small projects and i've hit a problem. Basically i get a '`NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE`' error while sending the request and i've no idea what is happening.

The HTML Page
(trimmed but shows the error)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <title>Ajax Test</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var COMPLETE = 4;
            var OK = 200;

            function GetXMLHttpRequestObject()
            {
                var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        }
                        catch (e)
                        {
                            XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                    }
                    catch (e)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                        }
                        catch (e)
                        {
                            XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
                }
                return XMLHttpRequestObject;
            }

            //The Main Ajax Object
            function AjaxRequest(p_RequestMethod, p_DestinationURL)
            {
                this.XMLHttpRequestObject = GetXMLHttpRequestObject();

                this.RequestedMethod = p_RequestMethod;
                this.DestinationURL = p_DestinationURL;

                this.XMLHttpRequestObject.open(this.RequestMethod, this.DestinationURL);

                this.OnStateChange = function(Callback)
                {
                    this.XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = Callback;
                }

                this.Send = function(p_Content)
                {
                    this.XMLHttpRequestObject.send(p_Content);
                }

                this.GetState()
                {
                    return this.XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState;
                }

                this.GetResponseText = function()
                {
                    return this.XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
                }

                this.GetResponseStatus = function()
                {
                    return this.XMLHttpRequestObject.status;
                }

                this.GetResponseStatusText = function()
                {
                    return this.XMLHttpRequestObject.statusText;
                }
            }

            var Request;

            function GetData()
            {
                Request = new AjaxRequest('POST', 'http://www.kalekold.net/ajax/Ajax.php');
                Request.OnStateChange = StateChange;
                Request.Send();
            }

            function StateChange()
            {
                window.alert("State: " + Request.GetState());
                window.alert("Response: " + Request.GetResponseStatus());
                window.alert("Response Text: " + Request.GetResponseStatusText());

                if(Request.GetState() == COMPLETE && Request.GetResponseStatus() == OK)
                {
                    Result = Request.GetResponseText();
                    window.alert(Result);
                }
            }
        </script> 

    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form>
            <textarea name="TextArea" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea><br />
            <input type="button" value="Load" onClick="GetData();">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

The PHP File:

```
<?php
$XML = <<< PROLOG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
PROLOG;

$XML .= "<results>";
    $XML .= "<result>";
        $XML .= "<FirstName>Gary</FirstName>";
        $XML .= "<SecondName>Willoughby</SecondName>";
        $XML .= "<Age>35</Age>";
    $XML .= "</result>";
    $XML .= "<result>";
        $XML .= "<FirstName>Sara</FirstName>";
        $XML .= "<SecondName>Gostick</SecondName>";
        $XML .= "<Age>35</Age>";
    $XML .= "</result>";
$XML .= "</results>";

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $XML;
?>
```

The full error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.open]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://www.kalekold.net/ajax/ :: AjaxRequest :: line 63"  data: no]

Line 0
```

I just can't see where it's going wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" is caused by an illegal value being passed into the call of open method.

Looking through your code I found misspelling:

```
this.RequestedMethod = p_RequestMethod;
this.DestinationURL = p_DestinationURL;

this.XMLHttpRequestObject.open(this.RequestMethod, this.DestinationURL);
```

See this.RequestedMethod property set to p_RequestMethod and this.RequestMethod being passed into the call of "open" method.

Also, instead of creating your own wrapper, I would recommend using open-source [XMLHttpRequest.js](http://code.google.com/p/xmlhttprequest/) - Standard-compliant cross-browser XMLHttpRequest object implementation, that also fixes some 20 bugs of browser's native XMLHttpRequest object implementations.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look. I am going to use another framework but i though i would roll my own as a learning experience. The above code is only a combined snippet of the main source. I was tired when looking for the problem. Again thanks.

Comment: Yep, spelling was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error message is one of the 'quirks' of FireFox's XMLHttpRequest object.  The same issue in IE will have different symptoms.

You don't want to deal with all these quirks yourself now that there's lots of good libraries out there.

For instance in Netscape and FX calling `XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText` or `XMLHttpRequestObject.status` throws an "NS_..." error for any connection problems.  IE will returns the OS network error code instead - no error thrown. If you handle this yourself you will have to build in the error handling for both.

I would recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) is also excellent.

Comment: I use jQuery now for Ajax. It's pretty awesome.