# 2 jquery versions on page cause trouble

Tags: jquery

I am working on something that is adding a jquery version to a page that already has jquery 1.2.6.

After loading jquery version 1.5.2 I run this:

```
new_$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now after page ready I run `new_$('.class')` and I get an error.

The problem exists only if the version of jquery is before 1.2.6

The error I am getting is:

`Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]`

Comment: *define: "an error"* ...

Comment: "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMXPathEvaluator.evaluate]"

Comment: As you can see here; http://jsfiddle.net/CU69u/ the code works as expected for me. You should come up with the minimum code required to reproduce this *unnamed error* if we've got any chance of helping you.

Comment: `@`Amit: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203161/how-to-get-around-a-ns-error-illegal-value-error-using-ajax

Comment: @Matt: I saw that question, but I am using jquery, and all i am doing is new_$('.class') there is no ajax request being made.

Comment: Well as you can see from the link I posted above (http://jsfiddle.net/CU69u/1/), you can't be doing *just* `new_$('.class');` as it works fine for me. Is this browser dependant? DOCTYPE? Other scripts you're including?

Comment: @Matt I made this fiddle for you to see the error. http://jsfiddle.net/4RsAa/4/

Answer (score 1):

You might try this.

```
<script src="foo/jquery.1.4.js" type="text/javascript></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   var oldJquery = jQuery;
   jQuery = null;
   $ = null;
   //]]>
</script>
<script src="foo/jquery.1.7.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

The sequence is essential.

**Edit**

Here it means:

1. Include jQuery (it is referenced by two variables `jQuery` and `$`
2. Assign the jQuery a new variable
3. Dereference `jQuery` and `$` (free those variables for further usage)
4. Include a newer version of jQuery